# Why the photos edited on lightroom desktop looks different in mobile phone?

Tags: lightroom, photo-editing, color-management, display-calibration

I am using Adobe Lightroom CC to edit photos on my computer. When I edit them on computer and export them it looks good on my computer.

But, when I copy same images on mobile device then they looks different. they look over saturated in mobile. (Colors are more saturated in mobile device).

Export settings in lightroom:

[image]

Comment: Mobile devices screens are not calibrated. They do whatever their manufacturer think is best to make images look good and induce sales. Did you ever see a test/review of a smartphone where the screen was checked for color accuracy? The same goes for audio, alas...

Comment: Not actually, I never saw any such test. also, what if I post the image exported from desktop as it is to instagram? will it look over saturated to other users based on their mobile's color accuracy or will it look like the same as desktop??

Comment: You can't tell. Maybe it is your own mobile that oversaturates things and other models are more accurate...  I wouldn't worry too much, people looking at pictures on their mobile aren't looking for color accuracy (ambient light ruins everything anyway).

Comment: It could equally be the computer that's out of true. No way to tell without calibration. You can, btw, calibrate phone screens if you have the right hardware/software … but that won't fix everyone else's ;)

Answer (score 3):

It is generally recommended to publish photos on the web in sRGB colour space. You have used the correct export setting.

Ideally you calibrate and profile your computer monitor. But this is a huge topic if you want to know all the details. It will be worth the effort if you earn money with photography or are doing prints and need soft-proofing.

The use of different colour spaces, lack of calibration and profiling is the cause of those differences in perception. You cannot do anything about other people's mobile devices. Most computer screens are too blue-ish and too bright and most mobile screens show colours too saturated - at least when you look at them in a room. Outdoors, with bright sunlight it might not be a bad thing to have a high saturation.

On some phones you can at least reduce saturation by changing a different profile. Additionally, Android's developer options let you enable the sRGB colour space for photos (I tried it with Android 10).

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I am surprised you expect them to be the same! Screens are very different and in both cases you adjust them in a myriad of ways. Even assuming your screen is calibrated, your file will have the correct colors but any display can show them differently. If your display is *not* calibrated and even you are not seeing the actual colors!

My phone for example has a standard and vivid mode which is the default and shows everything highly saturated but there are no finer controls for color-rendition. Even if you somehow managed to calibrate the cellphone, it in no way guarantees that colors will be the same. Calibration only makes colors that the screen *can* display more accurate, which is why you still see difference even between two calibrated screens.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people run into problems when editing on sRGB displays then posting to the web using the sRGB color space. Most people nowadays are viewing content on DCI-P3 displays which is becoming the new standard. If you edit on sRGB devices then view on a DCI-P3 device then things will look over saturated and skin tones can look like a lobster. Same applies if you edit on an RGB display the opposite can happen, colors on other devices will look under saturated and skin tones can look grey.

I edit my images on a DCI-P3 device so when I post anything online most people will be seeing something similar to what I was seeing on my P3 screen. I calibrate my display so things may look slightly different to others but that is difficult to resolve unless everybody calibrates their displays. Many people have Apple devices which are pretty dam accurate anyway.

Comment: Hi Phil and welcome to Photo.SE! Interesting to learn about the DCI-P3 colour space. If you have any sources about the prevalence of DCI-P3 displays (and Apple devices being accurate), could you please [edit] that into your answer? Otherwise it's hard to judge how you constructed that knowledge.